# Paypal Integration in iOS Mobile App

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have integrated the paypal in my iOS application using latest MPL library. The application runs fine in offline (ENV_NONE) mode. When I try test the app in Sandbox (ENV_SANDBOX) mode getting the following error in both simulator and device:

```
Checking Error********************
Posting Error: 2147483647
DEVELOPER ERROR: This app not using a supported version of the PayPal library.
```

Am using the sandbox testing APP ID "APP-80W284485P519543T"

Comment: I am currently having the same problem when using PayPal through a payment service (ZooZ.com). There seems to be something wrong since today. Googling on this error only shows posts from today.

Comment: @Wim Haanstra Please kindly let me know if u find any solution..

Comment: I received an updated framework lib from ZooZ which solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm getting the same problem, emailed PayPal support and got this -

> Regarding the 'Posting Error: 2147483647' error, this appears to be a
>   known issue that is currently being investigated. I will update you
>   via this ticket as soon as I get more update on this.

Hopefully it'll be resolved soon.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help

> The PayPal Sandbox has been configured to reject any HTTP requests without the “Host” header with HTTP 400 error. Merchants can use the Sandbox environment to certify the changes to their IPN and PDT scripts.

https://www.x.com/node/320404

Comment: Am using Mobile Payments Library latest version for iphone to integrate paypal into my iOS app. In my website it works fine. There is no option to add "Host" header in that library.